Chrome extension content.js not injecting
Im trying to create a google chrome extension that takes text from a website and sends it into an openAI API.
// popup.js
document.getElementById('highlight-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
    //Returns active tab and stored in tabs
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
        
        //returns text from tab and stores in response
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { action: "highlight" }, (response) => {

            if (response && response.text) {
                document.getElementById('output').innerText = response.text || "No text captured.";
            } else {
                document.getElementById('output').innerText = "No text captured.";
            }
            
            //sends text to openai api and stores the response in res
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "processText", text: response }, ( res ) => {
                if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                    console.log("Error sending message to background script:", chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
                    return;
                }
               
            });
        });
    });
});


// content.js
const captureText = () => {
    const bodyText = document.body.innerText || "";
    console.log("Extracted text:", bodyText);
    return bodyText;
};

// Listen for messages from background or popup
console.log("content script loaded");
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async (message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    console.log("Message received in content script:", message);
    if (message.action === "highlight") {
        console.log("Highlight action triggered");
        const text = captureText();
        sendResponse({ text }); // Send text back to background
    }
});


//manifest.json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Keyword Highlighter",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Capture words and highlight keywords on your screen.",
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "scripting", "storage", "tabs"],
    "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js",
        "type": "module"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["content.js"],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ],
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup/popup.html",
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "icons/icon.png",
            "48": "icons/icon.png",
            "128": "icons/icon.png"
        }
    }
}

I suspect that my content.js is not being injected as i have ran console.logs in my content.js file and it does not show up in my console. In a nutshell, the content.js file is not returning a response to my popup.js, therefore a null error.

Remove content_scripts and messaging, use executeScript as shown here.
